# On iOS, is it okay to read the UI outside of the main thread?

Tags: ios, mapkit

With iOS, I know that all *updates* to the UI must be done on the main thread. Are *reads* from the UI safe to do from outside of the main thread?

I have some computationally expensive logic that needs to use `MKMapView`'s `convertCoordinate` method, which needs `toPointToView: UIView`. Is this safe to do this from outside of the main thread?

Comment: // logic can be written in background threadCGPoint startPoint = [ffMapView convertCoordinate:startCoordinate toPointToView:self.view];
but final out come like add subview or view animation must be in main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do frame calculation or whatever logic in back ground. But UI operations like add subview , animation must be in main thread.

```
CGPoint annPoint = [self.mapView convertCoordinate:coord toPointToView:self.mapView];    
     mapPic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"]];
     mapPic.frame = CGRectMake(annPoint.x, annPoint.y, 32, 32);
     [self.view addSubview:macPic];
```

it can be written as per your requirement:

```
- (void)doCalculation
{
    //you can use any string instead "com.mycompany.myqueue"
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myqueue", 0);

    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        CGPoint annPoint = [self.mapView convertCoordinate:coord toPointToView:self.mapView];    
     mapPic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"]];
     mapPic.frame = CGRectMake(annPoint.x, annPoint.y, 32, 32);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.view addSubview:macPic];
        });    
    });
}
```

hope it will help